# Fetch data from two tables with PDO

Tags: php, sql, pdo, mariadb

How to fetch data from two tables with fetchAll()?

SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM `students` INNER JOIN `classes` ON `students`.`class` = `classes`.`ID_class`
```

I need fetch `students.name`, `students.surname`, `students.username`, `classes.name`.

I fetch data with foreach.

Comment: what is the structure of your database ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the tables and columns you want instead of using `*`.

```
SELECT s.name, s.surname, s.username, c.name
FROM students AS s
JOIN classes AS c
ON s.class = c.ID_class;
```